# Google Cloud credentials with Terraform

Tags: google-cloud-platform, terraform, terraform-provider-gcp, terragrunt

This is a bit of a newbie question, but I've just gotten started with GCP provisioning using Terraform / Terragrunt, and I find the workflow with obtaining GCP credentials quite confusing. I've come from using AWS exclusively, where obtaining credentials, and configuring them in the AWS CLI was quite straightforward.

Basically, the [Google Cloud Provider documentation](https://www.terraform.io/docs/providers/google/provider_reference.html) states that you should define a `provider` block like so:

```
provider "google" {
  credentials = "${file("account.json")}"
  project     = "my-project-id"
  region      = "us-central1"
  zone        = "us-central1-c"
}
```

This `credentials` field shows I (apparently) must generate a service account, and keep a JSON somewhere on my filesystem.

However, if I run the command `gcloud auth application-default login`, this generates a token located at `~/.config/gcloud/application_default_credentials.json`; alternatively I can also use `gcloud auth login <my-username>`. From there I can access the Google API (which is what Terraform is doing under the hood as well) from the command line using a `gcloud` command.

So why does the Terraform provider require a JSON file of a service account? Why can't it just use the credentials that the `gcloud` CLI tool is already using?

By the way, if I configure Terraform to point to the `application_default_credentials.json` file, I get the following errors:

> Initializing modules...
>
> Initializing the backend...
>
> Error: Failed to get existing workspaces: querying Cloud Storage
>   failed: Get
>   https://www.googleapis.com/storage/v1/b/terraform-state-bucket/o?alt=json&delimiter=%2F&pageToken=&prefix=projects%2Fsomeproject%2F&prettyPrint=false&projection=full&versions=false:
>   private key should be a PEM or plain PKCS1 or PKCS8; parse error:
>   asn1: syntax error: sequence truncated

Answer (score 17, accepted):

> if I configure Terraform to point to the application_default_credentials.json file, I get the following errors:

The `credentials` field in provider config expects a path to service account key file, not user account credentials file. If you want to authenticate with your user account try omitting `credentials` and then running `gcloud auth application-default login`; <s>if Terraform doesn't find your credentials file you can set the `GOOGLE_APPLICATION_CREDENTIALS` environment variabe to point to `~/.config/gcloud/application_default_credentials.json`</s>.

Read [here for more](https://cloud.google.com/docs/authentication/) on the topic of service accounts vs user accounts. For what it's worth, Terraform docs explicitly advice against using `application-default login`:

> This approach isn't recommended- some APIs are not compatible with credentials obtained through gcloud

Similarly [GCP docs](https://cloud.google.com/docs/authentication/) state the following:

> Important: For almost all cases, whether you are developing locally or in a production application, you should use service accounts, rather than user accounts or API keys.

Comment: Ah, I see now, thank you very much! I was so confused about why this happens. The part that you mention from the Terraform Docs ("This approach isn't recommended- some APIs are not compatible with credentials obtained through gcloud") still worries me a bit. That implies that *some* actions I cannot do through a regular `gcloud` command. That seems very strange.

Comment: actually it looks like a user *must* use a service account. When I do your recommended steps, and point `GOOGLE_APPLICATION_CREDENTIALS` to `~/.config/gcloud/application_default_credentials.json`, it still gives me the error above, saying that it's not in PEM format.

Comment: Oh right, my bad. Does `application-default login` still work if you unset the `GOOGLE_APPLICATION_CREDENTIALS` variable?

Comment: FWIW, the linked 'GCP Docs' no longer contain the 'you should use service accounts' phrase. User accounts don't seem to be discouraged, and appear to be intended for developers.

Comment: Currently, during development, using the `gcloud auth application-default login` method is recommended both by [Google](https://cloud.google.com/iam/docs/best-practices-service-accounts#development) (Instead, let them use your credentials by running ... `gcloud auth application-default login`) and by [Terraform](https://registry.terraform.io/providers/hashicorp/google/latest/docs/guides/getting_started#configuring-the-provider) (The easiest way to do this is to run `gcloud auth application-default login`)

Answer (score 0):

Change the credentials to point directly to the file location. Everything else looks good.

Example: credentials = "/home/scott/gcp/FILE_NAME"

Answer (score -1):

Still it is not recommended to use `gcloud auth application-default login`, Best best approaches  are

https://www.terraform.io/docs/providers/google/guides/provider_reference.html#credentials-1

Comment: this is wrong, the same link, https://registry.terraform.io/providers/hashicorp/google/latest/docs/guides/provider_reference#credentials-1 states: If you are using Terraform on your workstation we recommend that you install gcloud and authenticate using User Application Default Credentials ("ADCs") as a primary authentication method. You can enable ADCs by running the command gcloud auth application-default login.

Comment: In my case the senario was different but this was the only thing that works