# Failed to get existing workspaces: querying Cloud Storage failed: storage: bucket doesn't exist

Tags: terraform, google-cloud-build

I was using terraform in cloud build, but it fails at this step

```js
steps:
  # Terraform
  - id: 'configure_terraform'
    name: node:10.16.3
    entrypoint: "node"
    args: ["./create_terraform_config.js",
           "../terraform/override.tf",
           "${_TERRAFORM_BUCKET_NAME}",
           "${_TERRAFORM_BUCKET_PATH}"]
    dir: "app/scripts"
  - id: 'init_terraform'
    name: hashicorp/terraform:light
    args: ["init"]
    dir: "app/terraform"
```

```
Initializing the backend...

Successfully configured the backend "gcs"! Terraform will automatically
use this backend unless the backend configuration changes.

Error: Failed to get existing workspaces: querying Cloud Storage failed: storage: bucket doesn't exist
```

Answer (score 36, accepted):

This might fix the issue

```
terraform init -reconfigure
```

reference: https://github.com/hashicorp/terraform/issues/23532#issuecomment-560493391

Comment: In my case, `terraform init -reconfigure` produced the same error.

I was able to resolve my issue via [@Oliver](https://stackoverflow.com/a/72382324/3542457)'s solution of changing the [application-default login](https://cloud.google.com/sdk/gcloud/reference/auth/application-default/login).

Answer (score 32):

This is what worked for me:

```
gcloud auth application-default login --project $PROJECT
```

Normally I omit the `--project` arg but that still generated the error. I thought it was only used for billing/quota. This may be a bug related to my specific tool versions:

```
Google Cloud SDK 387.0.0
Terraform v1.1.2
```

Comment: This should be the accepted answer, detail in [terraofrm's docs](https://registry.terraform.io/providers/hashicorp/google/latest/docs/guides/getting_started#adding-credentials). A bit more detail can be found [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/57455958/799379)

Comment: This worked for me too. Selecting a project worked for me.

Answer (score 2):

1. State bucket must be pre-existing.
   [GCS backend bucket must pre-exist](https://github.com/hashicorp/terraform/issues/18417)

If it doesn't exist, create the state bucket and version it, using the following commands:

```
gsutil mb -p <projectId> -c <storage-class> -l <region> -b gs://<bucket-name>
gsutil versioning set on gs://<bucket-name>
```

2. As specified in the above answer execute terraform init with
   -reconfigure option.

Answer (score 1):

This can happen if you have previously exported the `GOOGLE_APPLICATION_CREDENTIALS` var in your current terminal.

To check that you can run `gcloud auth application-default login`. You will have the following output:

```
The environment variable [GOOGLE_APPLICATION_CREDENTIALS] is set to:
  [/home/alphayax/gcp/xxxxxxxxx-123456789abc.json]
Credentials will still be generated to the default location:
  [/home/alphayax/.config/gcloud/application_default_credentials.json]
To use these credentials, unset this environment variable before
running your application.
```

So you just have to unset the env var with the following:

```bash
export GOOGLE_APPLICATION_CREDENTIALS=
```

Comment: Thank you, @alphayax. Your suggestion proved effective for me. I simply executed gcloud auth login and followed the steps, and everything went smoothly.